# Does an empty foreground service keep an android app alive?

Tags: android, flutter, background

I'm working on an app that keeps communicating with a device by Bluetooth(ble) when it's in both foreground mode and background mode.

I know I should implement ble jobs in a foreground service in Android, but the app is written in flutter and all codes are in dart.

It seems that for now even though there isn't a foreground service, the app keeps alive in background mode.

But I want it to be alive as long as possible.
So I'm thinking about making an empty foreground service...

Will an empty foreground service make an app has some priority in background mode?

And is it ok to do so?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an "empty" Foreground Service will usually prevent the app process from being killed automatically by the system, unless the device is critically low on memory.

How the code in the service class itself looks like does not matter. The important thing is that when a Foreground Service is running in the app process, the whole process will be prevented from being killed. This means that you can have Dart threads in the same process that won't be killed. Activities belonging to the same process that are in the background can still be "destroyed" though, i.e. the onDestroy callback can be called.

Since BLE connections in Android uses the Binder mechanism which are not tied to any of the standard Components (Service, Broadcast Receiver, Activity, ...) that otherwise control how the app process stays alive, having an "empty" Foreground Service is actually a common way to keep BLE connections alive.

Answer (score 0):

The system can terminate an application in the background at any point. In practice if there is no need for its resources, it runs several minutes maybe more.

When using a foreground service, at some point only the service will run, so there is no real use of "empty service". Closing the application manually will leave only the service running.